# getXMLHTTP statusText variable in object not found status !=200

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, html, mysqli

So I posted this earlier, before I isolated the problem, and thought I would repost with the problem isolated, it happens between these two functions. When I update my State, it calls the getCity function, which seems fine. The Call is happening.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function getXMLHTTP() {
       var ret = false;
       try {
          x = new XMLHttpRequest();
       }catch(e) {
         try {
            x = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }catch(ex) {
            try {
                req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e1) {
                x = false;
            }
         }
      }
      return x;
    }
 function getCity(stateId)
 {
  var strURL="findCity.php?state="+stateId;
  var req = getXMLHTTP();
  if (req)
  {
    req.onreadystatechange = function()
     {
       if (req.readyState == 4) // only if "OK"
       {
          if (req.status == 200)
          {
              document.getElementById('citydiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;
          } else {
              alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);//This Is the statement I am getting
          }
       }
     }
     req.open("GET", strURL, true);
     req.send(null);
  }
}
```

So the call happens to both functions, but the object returned to getCity by getXMLHTTP has a statusText variable of not found. which means none of the other conditions are applicable to it.

I looked high and low, here and elsewhere or this problem, and just reached dead ends, I even looked at w3c's documentation for the object, but it is brief to say the least, what might cause this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms759127(v=vs.85).aspx it looks like the statusText property wasn't implemented in the MSXML API until MSXML3.  Since you're calling an MSXML2 API I would guess that is where your error is coming from.  Is this problem isolated to a specific browser or platform?

By the way, dottoro is a great site for looking up documentation on this kind of thing: http://help.dottoro.com/ljtutikf.php#supByObj

Comment: Every time I code this happens, I stare at it too long and miss it, I should have carefully read firebug. I typed the name of my php file incorrectly, it was fincity, not findCity. Thank you for the documentation link nonetheless, and the help updating my api requests.